# Vertical alignment of consecutive minipages and `twoside`

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, minipage, double-sided

I am experiencing a strange issue with the vertical position of minipages on a page when I am using `twoside`. The issue is best explained using an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \section{Heading}

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \LARGE \lipsum[3]
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \LARGE \lipsum[3]
  \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this code, I get a document containing two pages. Each page contains one of the minipages and they are aligned at the top of their respective page (after the heading):

[image: Page 1] [image: Page 2]

If I add the document class option `twopage`, however (`\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}`), the first minipage suddenly is at the bottom of the first page; the second page does not change:

[image: Page 1 using <code>twoside</code>]

Interestingly, this does not happen without the `\section{Heading}`.

The question is obviously: how can I get the minipage to the top of the page? I am especially interested in a solution where there can be an arbitrary/unknown number of minipages on the first page (as many as fit on the page). All of them should be at the top-most possible location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`article` uses  `\raggedbottom` by default, so if pages fall short any additional space is added at the bottom of the page. in twoside mode it defaults to `\flushbottom` so it tries to ensure the bottom line is at the bottom of each page but as all your text is in a minipage the only stretchy space is the space above the minipage below the heading, the second page has no stretch space so will be under-full.

As far as I understand your description you want `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Note that your first minipage is not indented due to the heading but as written your later ones will be indented and so the lines will be over-full by `\parindent`.

Comment: `\raggedbottom` is indeed what I want. Maybe it might be useful to point out that this is not limited to `article` but also to other classes (I tried `book` and `scrarctl`).

Comment: @JPW `\raggedbottom` is defined in the format but which is the default depends on the class "article" classes tend to default to ragged, "book" classes tend to default to flush.